# Nginx HTTP to HTTPS redirect only working on one server_name?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, https

I've been trying to get http to https redirect via nginx for the better part of a day, and it's been a struggle. I've checked over several stackoverflow questions, and a number of articles on the internet. I finally got http to https redirect, but only for the direct ip address, not the domain I'm trying to use.

So in other words, http://12.345.67.890 redirects to https://app.example.com, but http://app.example.com does not redirect to https://app.example.com.

Is this expected? What don't I understand here?

**My site's config file**

```
upstream appupstream {
    server 0.0.0.0:3555;
}

server {
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;
    server_name app.example.com 12.345.67.890;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    root /home/ec2-user/app/public;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass https://appupstream;
    }
}
```

When I curl these sites, the headers seem to support what I'm seeing in my browsers:

**IP curl results**

```
$ curl -I -L http://12.345.67.890
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently  // <-- Note the permanent redirect on the ip
Server: nginx/1.12.1
Date: Sat, 03 Nov 2018 19:30:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://app.example.com/

HTTP/2 200
date: Sat, 03 Nov 2018 19:30:10 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length: 4856
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-download-options: noopen
strict-transport-security: max-age=15778476; includeSubDomains
p3p: ABCDEF
```

**Domain curl results**

```
$ curl -I -L http://app.example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK                     // <-- No permanent redirect on domain
Date: Sat, 03 Nov 2018 19:30:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 4856
Connection: keep-alive
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15778476; includeSubDomains
P3P: ABCDEF
```

I've run `nginx -t` successfully, and I've used both `nginx reload` and `nginx restart` each time I've updated the file. I've cleared ALL browsing data (cookies, etc.) and revisited, but this behavior persists. Any suggestions/guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Any particular reason why you have the ip address down as a server name?

Comment: Just for testing. I direct traffic through a cpanel account on the top-level domain (example.com) to my AWS load balancer via subdomain (app.example.com), so I added in the ip address so I could (hopefully) rule out any propagation delay issues from my cpanel VPS account with my other host, which I have for ease in setting up email addresses and such. With the ip, I can ping my EC2 instance directly.